# Print out a string of characters from a 2D array into a certain number of rows

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a keypad in Java that takes letters input by the user, as well as a desired number of characters per row. It should then print the characters in the desired number of rows, so if `"abcdefgh"` is input and the desired row number is 4 it should print:

```
abcd  
efgh
```

but I'm stuck on how to get it to work.

```
public class Keypad {

char [][] letters; 

public Keypad(String chars, int rowLength) {
    int counter = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i<chars.length(); i++){
        counter++; 
    }
    letters = new char[rowLength][counter/rowLength];  
}

public String toString() {
    String s = " "; 

    for (int row=0; row<letters.length; row=row+1) { // Over rows
        for (int col=0; col<letters[row].length; col=col+1) {  
            s = s + letters[row][col];
        }
        s = s + "\n";
    }
    return "the keypad is" + s; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the logic of the `toString()` method looks fine, but you didn't populate the `letters` array in the constructor. So you need to add something like this in the constructor:

```
    public Keypad(String chars, int rowLength) {
        // you don't need to count the length with a loop
        int nRow = chars.length()/rowLength;
        if(chars.length()%rowLength!=0) nRow++;
        letters = new char[nRow][rowLength];

        for(int i = 0, n = 0 ; i < letters.length ; i++) {
            for(int j = 0 ; n < chars.length() && j < letters[i].length ; j++, n++) {
                letters[i][j] = chars.charAt(n);
            }
        }
    }
```